# How to delete an object from angularJs Model?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a function that enables me to remove an item when the button is clicked. My ng-repeat is below :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myData.List">
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.item}}</td>                
            <td><button type="submit" ng-click="delete(x.id)" class="button">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
```

and my delete function is :

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {            
     var index = $scope.myData.List.indexOf(id);
     $scope.myData.List.splice(index,1);               
};
```

But problem is that it delete the last object. But I want delete a particular item. what should I do ?

Comment: can you provide your myData it is array of objects or simple array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in not a angular specific problem. Array Splice is related JavaScript array manipulation. Pass only the index `x` instead of `x.id`. So your html code will be..

```
<td><button type="submit" ng-click="delete(x)" class="button">Remove</button></td>

$scope.delete = function (x) {            
     var index = $scope.myData.List.indexOf(x);
     $scope.myData.List.splice(index,1);               
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `x` instead of its `id` in `.indexOf`:

```
$scope.delete = function (x) {            
     var index = $scope.myData.List.indexOf(x);
     $scope.myData.List.splice(index,1);               
};
```

and

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="delete(x)" class="button">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Its working but I need the id's value also . so how can i get that ?

Comment: @DropShadow, use `x.id`, i.e `function(x){ console.log(x.id)}`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `myData.List` is a collection of objects not ids.
You need to search for the `id`

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {            
  var index=-1;
  for(;index<$scope.myData.List.length;index++){
   if($scope.myData.List.id===id)
     break;
  }
  if(index!==-1){
   $scope.myData.List.splice(index,1);               
  }
}
```

Or you can pass the object to the function as Nicolai posted